# Python pandas SettingWithCopyWarning

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I wonder why the first code (that reads data from CSV) has a warning message `SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame`, while the second code (that uses the same logic, but manual DataFrame initialization) does not have this warning message.

Code #1

```
import pandas as pd

myData = pd.read_csv('https://spark-public.s3.amazonaws.com/dataanalysis/loansData.csv')

for i in range(len(myData['Employment.Length'])):
    myData['Employment.Length'][i] = 3
```

Code #2

```
list1 = ['bla', 'la', 'lal']    
list2 = [1, 2, 3]      
myData = pd.DataFrame({'1': list1, '2':list2})  

for i in range(len(myData)):  
    myData['1'][i] = 3
```

Comment: Yes, I got both warnings in python 2.7 & pandas 0.16.2

Comment: When run in console the said warning is shown only once per console. So if you run the both the codes the same python console you will only see the warning first time. When tried with ipython notebook I am getting the warning on both codes.

Comment: I get warnings for both, what version of pandas and where are you running the code from?

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham: I am running the code in PyCharm (Python 2.7). Regarding pandas I'm not sure about the version. I've just installed it with 'pip install pandas'

Comment: Must be 16.0.2 then, I cannot replicate using pycharm, 2.7 and the same version of pandas both messages are propagated whether run in the same or different files. Do you have any interpreter params/options  set in pycharm for your second file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the above codes generate the same warning. When both codes are run in same python application/console the warning is generated twice (once from each code) but it is reported only once due to the **warnings filter** being set to **once**

> **once**: print only the first occurrence of matching warnings, regardless 
>   of location.
>   **always**: always print matching warnings

Refer [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/warnings.html#the-warnings-filter)

To change this behavior set **warnings filter** to **always**

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("always")
```

Comment: I have both codes saved as *.py files. In PyCharm I run them separately. Each time I execute Code1 it generates the warning, while code2.py does not generate any warnings. I'm not using console. Do you have any idea why this happens?

Comment: I made another test - putted both codes in the same *.py file and added "import warnings   warnings.filterwarnings("always")". Now it generates warning message two times. Then I go back to code2.py, just in case I add "import warnings   warnings.filterwarnings("always")" and the warning does not appear again...

Comment: @KlausosKlausos I am not familiar with pycharm behavior. However I tried with *py files and executed the code from commandline and the warnings appeared every time. I tested with python2.7 and python3 on ubuntu 14

Comment: Well, probably some pycharm's error. Anyway, thanks for the answer.